# path structure in carrierwave with a name not included in the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

My models are as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :info, :class_name => "PostulantInfo"
  mount_uploader :curriculum_vitae, DocumentUploader

#...

class PostulantInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :relatives
  has_many :studies, :class_name => "HighSchoolStudy", :foreign_key => :postulant_info_id

  mount_uploader :marriage_certificate, DocumentUploader
  mount_uploader :photo1, FaceImageUploader
  mount_uploader :photo2, SideFaceImageUploader

#...

class Relative < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :birth_certificate, DocumentUploader

#...

class HighSchoolStudy < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :degree_certificate, DocumentUploader
#...
```

Actually I just have the default store_dir:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

So this is creating a directory structure like:

```
 - uploads
  - user
   - curriculum_vitae
    - {user.id}
     - {the_file}
  -postulant_info
   - marriage_certificate
    - {postulant_info.id}
     - {the_file}
   - photo1
    - {postulant_info.id}
     - {the_file}
   - photo2
    - {postulant_info.id}
     - {the_file}
   - and so on...
```

But I want something like:

```
 - uploads
  - {user.uuid}
   - {all_the_files_for_this_user}
```

The problem is I don't know how to give `user.uuid`, for example, when I want to save the `marriage_certificate` file of `PostulantInfo`. I was looking the [wiki](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki) for a while, but I couldn't find something that could be helpful for this problem.
Thinking in a possible solution could be add an uuid attribute to each of the models containing files, then copy the user.uuid to each one and save it to the db, but this would be a waste of resources.
A less messy solution could be access to the parent model, for example to `PostulantInfo` model, and do something like:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.user.uuid}"
end
```

But this implies that:

- Make an Uploader for each offspring level
- Add `belongs_to :PostulantInfo` to `Relative` and `HighSchoolStudy`, where there's no reason for these models know about their Parent (except know the uuid obviously)
- Each time that I want to render a link to the file, rails will make a db query to know the uuid, when is something that I already have thanks to Devise in `current_user.uuid`

What should be the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance